# Question about scoping. Why isn't it printing x in the console?

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm kinda confused on global/local scopes. I have the following code:

```
var x = 12

function a() {
  console.log(x)
} //nothing being logged to the console

x = 12

function a() {
  console.log(x)
} //12 being logged to the console
```

x is created in the global scope for both scenarios if I'm not mistaken? However, only the second scenario (x = 12) is able to log the value of x to the console. Can someone kindly explain why?

Thank you.

Comment: @Bravo you shouldn't fix the OP's code directly in the original question.

Comment: @Bravo thank you for the input. I understand if you were to call a(), 12 would be logged to the console. However, if I left the code how it was before (without calling function a), the first one prints nothing but the second one prints out 12. Do you know what might be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: @Ycfan23 - are you entering this in the console? the result of `var a = 12` in the console is different from just `a = 12` in the console, as the first can't be used in the RHS of an expression but the second can .... i.e. `b = a = 12` is valid, `b = var a = 12` is not. I've learned a long time ago that the console is NOT a place to learn how javascript WORKS

Comment: @Ycfan23, if you just run the line `x = 12` without anything else, is that the same output you see when you run the code in your question? (Edit: I see Bravo is thinking along the same line as I am)

Comment: @Bravo "the result of var a = 12 in the console is different from just a = 12 in the console, as the first can't be used in the RHS of an expression but the second can .... i.e. b = a = 12 is valid, b = var a = 12 is not" I didn't know this at all and that's where my lack of understanding is! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know the code you posted was entered into the console, so apologies for initially editing your code